# Special characters and MSI

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, orca

I have to have password input into an msi I created using Visual studio 2008. But I notice that if a password have ‘ “ ‘ character in it. I Get a FileNotFoundException. Is there a setting in Orca that can correct this? Have tried other special character and they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not special characters, but the '/' character at the end off the text box. If you need to use it at the end the user has to input ut like this '//'.